# Top R package for PLS regression?

Tags: r, partial-least-squares

I'm very new to **R** and PLS-regression. I would like to know, based on your experience, which **R** packages for PLS-regression are most highly recommended. My area of application is chemistry.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for statistical packages.

Answer (score 4):

Each package has been developed for some specific purposes although they may all have some "Partial least squares regression" term as the their general explanation. For example

- Package [plsRglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plsRglm/plsRglm.pdf) is designed for Partial least squares Regression for (weighted) generalized linear models and kfold crossvalidation of such models using various criteria.
- Package [plsRcox](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plsRcox/plsRcox.pdf) is good for Partial least squares Regression and various regular, sparse or kernel, techniques for fitting Cox models in high dimensional settings.
- Package [pls](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/pls.pdf) is developed for Partial Least Squares Regression (PLSR), Principal Component Regression (PCR) and Canonical Powered Partial Least Squares (CPPLS).

Maybe for the chemistry the package [pls](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/pls.pdf) would be more suitable since it has been mentioned (as an example) on page 2 of the [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/) in [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02/paper).

Depending on what you are modeling, what is your model and the approach you may decide to go with a different package. One last thing, if a package is not reliable in R, then it will be removed from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).